# ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync running it across partition keys

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to have one stored procedure which I need to run on different partition keys. My collection is partitioned on one key entityname and I want to execute the stored procecure on each entity in the partition.

```
sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collectionLink, sproc,
    new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionkey) });

StoredProcedureResponse<int> scriptResult = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(
    sproc.SelfLink,
    new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionkey) },
    args);
```

I get the following exception:

> Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted

1. Is it necessary to create a stored procedure in each partition based on key?
2. Is it possible to have one stored procedure which can execute for all keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stored procedure is executed from client, RequestOptions specify the partition key, stored procedure will run in context of this partition and cannot operate (e.g. create) on docs that have different partition key value.

What you can do is to execute the sproc from client for each partition key. For instance, if sproc is to bulk-create documents, you can group the docs by partition key and send each group (can be done in parallel) to the sproc providing partition key value in RequestOptions. Would that be helpful?

You don't have to create sproc for each partition key, just create once without providing partition key.

Comment: We are working on a stored procedure that will run across partition keys. Stay tuned.

Comment: Hi @RajeshNagpal has that been completed now?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed the above in Java.

There are differences in how we implement while using Java SDK and stored procedure.

Please note the use of 'string' and the need to separate records based on partition key.

Bulk Import Store Procedure used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming

**Below is the client calling the store procedure**

```
public void CallStoredProcedure(Map <String, List<String>> finalMap)
{
    for ( String key : finalMap.keySet() ) {
        try
        {
            ExecuteStoredProcedure(finalMap.get(key),key);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.info(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }       
}
public void ExecuteStoredProcedure(List<String> documents, String partitionKey)
{

    try {

        if (documentClient == null) {
            documentClient = new DocumentClient(documentDBHostUrl, documentDBAccessKey, null, ConsistencyLevel.Session);
        }

        options = new RequestOptions();
        options.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey(partitionKey));

        Object[] sprocsParams = new Object[2] ;
        sprocsParams[0] = documents;
        sprocsParams[1] = null;

        StoredProcedureResponse rs = documentClient.executeStoredProcedure(selflink, options, sprocsParams);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```